# Ruby on Rails "render json:" ignoring alias_attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, render, alias

I have the following code in my **account.rb** model file:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute :id, :accountID
  alias_attribute :name, :awzAccountName
  alias_attribute :description, :awzAccountDescription
end
```

And the following code in the **index** method from my **accounts_controller.rb** file:

```
def index
    @accounts = Account.all

    if params["page"]
      page = params["page"]
      items_per_page = params["per_page"]

      render :json => {:total => @accounts.count,:accounts => @accounts.page(page).per(items_per_page) }
    else
      render json: @accounts
    end
end
```

As expected, `render json: @accounts` returns a result set that contains the `alias_attribute` column names defined in the model file.  However, the `render :json => {:total => @accounts.count,:accounts => @accounts.page(page).per(items_per_page) }` code returns a result set that contains the original column names.  Is there any way to change this so that the `alias_attribute` column names are used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't expect `render json: @accounts` to include the aliased attributes at all. The `alias_attribute` just gives you the luxury of referring to the attribute with another name - it doesn't replace the original name at all.

If you do want to include the aliases in your json output for a model you can override `as_json` and add those methods explicitly:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  options[:methods] ||= []
  options[:methods] += [:name, :description]
  super(options)
end
```

(I've deliberately omitted `:id` as that may be a special case - not entirely sure and can't test locally at the moment)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I added the method you posted to my account.rb file (below the alias_attributes), but the method is not getting called when I call @accounts.to_json from the controller.  Do you know why this is?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by overwriting [`serializable_hash`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html#method-i-serializable_hash) method.

```
def serializable_hash(options = {})
  options[:methods] ||= []
  options[:methods] += [:name, :description]
  super(options)
end
```

You can achieve the same result by passing `methods` argument to `as_json` without changing your default serialization of your models. like this:

```
render json: @accounts.as_json(methods: [:name, :description])
```

Comment: This is a better option in the case where your model is included in other models. If you just override `to_json`/`as_json`, you'll run into the problem where it only works when rendering the model as a root. If the model is a child of other models, `to_json`/`as_json` is not called but `serializable_hash` *is*.